# regular expression for javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My string is like this - "Some text &&Power Cable&& more text &&Supervisor&&

Now I have an array which contains values like - arr[0]=Power Cable and arr[1]=Supervisor. so what I want to do is- parse my string and find out these tokens out of it which in this case are - 1) Power Cable and 2) Supervisor and then compare these tokens to those I have in my array.

Note that there can be n number of tokens in the string(all dynamic) and they can be anywhere, meaning at the start of the string or at the end or somewhere in middle. I tried few regex but none of them are giving me the result I want.

Comment: The simplest I tried is - msgText  = msgText.replace(/&amp;&amp;/g,'');
  var tokenArr = [];
  tokenArr = msgText.split(' '); However, it splits my token Power Cable into 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [JavaScript split() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var str = "Some text &&Power Cable&& more text &&Supervisor&&";
var result = str.split("&&");
```

Comment: I think what I was doing wrong was replacing all the "&" at the first step. if i do split without replace, it gives me my tokens correctly. Thanks for the pointer !